# failed to load / invalid sound zero-length duration reported chrome, firefox

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, firefox, soundmanager2

failed to load / invalid sound zero-length duration reported chrome,firefox 
i get result only in IE10. In other browser, it shows the error message "failed to load / invalid sound zero-length duration reported"

my code is below

foo = soundManager.createSound({
      id: 'bar',
      url: '../music/_mp3/xx02.mp3'
    });

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your flash version and if necessary update it at flashVersion: 9

If it doesn't work, it's possible that you're using mp3 encoded in a particular way that the browser can't read.

So try to encode again mp3 file in a standard way. (I've solved the same issue in this way)

Source: https://getsatisfaction.com/schillmania/topics/zero_length_duration_reported_in_firefox_ie9_but_not_webkit